# How to get distinct values and their count from the first column of excel using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

My excel sheet "abc.xls" contains 4 columns like below in column A to D with A1:D1 containing header information i.e. Sample Number, Time, Name, Man:-

```
Sample number   Time                Name           Man
100             28-10-2014 20:24    absjsdj        abc
1000            28-10-2014 20:13    def            jss
800             29-10-2014 20:13    skdjksj        def
100             30-10-2014 20:13    skdjksj        def
1000            31-10-2014 20:13    skdjksj        def
700             01-11-2014 20:13    skdjksj        def
600             02-11-2014 20:13    skdjksj        def
```

Using c# code, I have used the below code to open this excel file; now i need help in implementing that functionality:

```
using Excel = = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
                    excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

                    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
                    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
                    xlWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("abc.xls");
                    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
```

and get the distinct numbers from column A i.e. from this excel data, we should get 100, 1000, 800, 700, 600 and the number of times each sample number occurred like 100 occurred 2 times, 1000 occurred 2 times, 800 occurred 1 time, 700 occurred 1 time, 600 occurred 1 time.

Once that information is extracted, I want to display the output on the windows form using any read only control listbox,label,textbox in the following manner:-

```
100  : 2
1000 : 2
800  : 1
700  : 1
600  : 1
```

Comment: you can use LinqToExcel nuget Package ...

Comment: Would like to see what you've tried.

Comment: I am not sure how to achieve this..so need help regarding the same..

Comment: What specific question do you want to be answered ? What have you tried to do this until now ?

Comment: I have opened the excel file using above code..now i need to write c# code to achieve those search on that excel explained above.

Answer (score 0):

You can **loop through excel** using code similar to the snippet below.
You can e.g. store the values in a dictionary `Dictionary<int,List<string>>` to store string values collected from every column.
Then, convert it to date, int, float or other data type you need, using DateTime.Parse, Int.Parse etc.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReadExcel.PrintAllCells(@"D:\some_place\some_excel.xlsx");
    }

}
public class ReadExcel
{
    public static void PrintAllCells(string location)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(location);


        foreach (var xlWorksheet in xlWorkbook.Worksheets)
        {
            Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

            // LOOPING THROUGH EXCEL CELLS STARTS WITH 1 
            // NOT WITH 0

            for (int column = 1; column < colCount; column++)
            {
                for (int row = 1; row < rowCount; row++)
                {

                    var CellData = xlRange.Cells[row, column].Value;
                    Console.WriteLine(CellData);

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```